# Bash: rsync push_dir "<filename>" failed: Not a directory

Tags: directory, push, rsync, aix

How i find files i want to rsync:

```
$files=$(find /tmp -mtime -4 -name '*.abc' -type f 2>/dev/null)

$echo $files
$/tmp/file.abc /tmp/newfile.abc
```

Rsync command:

```
rsync -v -a --progress --stats --rsh="ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no" --files-from=`echo $files` user@target_host:/tmp/
```

Error i see:

```
building file list ...
push_dir "/tmp/newfile.abc" failed: Not a directory
rsync error: errors selecting input/output files, dirs (code 3) at flist.c(1055)
```

Rsync version:

```
$rsync --version
rsync  version 2.6.2  protocol version 28
Copyright (C) 1996-2004 by Andrew Tridgell and others
<http://rsync.samba.org/>
Capabilities: 64-bit files, socketpairs, hard links, symlinks, batchfiles,
          no IPv6, 32-bit system inums, 64-bit internal inums
```

How do i accomplish the rsync?

Comment: `find /tmp -mtime -4 -name '*.abc' -type f 2>/dev/null >~/filelist; rsync --files-from ~/filelist ...`

Comment: @LorinczyZsigmond does your method create a temporary file? I don't want to create a temporary file

Comment: `rsync -v -a --progress --stats --rsh="ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no" -- $files user@target_host:/tmp/` -- but avoid filenames that contain spaces

Comment: @LorinczyZsigmond you can post your most recent comment as an answer if you want. It worked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"rsync --files-from=-" accepts piping if the - is specified, hence:

```
find /tmp -mtime -4 -name '*.abc' -type f 2>/dev/null | rsync -v -a --progress --stats --rsh="ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no" --files-from=- user@target_host:/tmp/
```